# Get issue when use virtual camera on Windows Subsystem - Windows 11

Tags: android, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem using OBS virtual cameras when using them with Android Subsystem on Windows 11.
Specifically, applications on Android Subsystem Windows (ASW) cannot recognize virtual cameras from OBS. Because these applications cannot select the default camera like when used with Zoom, Skype or Chrome... I tried to check with the command:

`"adb shell dumpsys media.camera"`
[image: This is result]
The results show that ASW only accepts built-in camera devices but does not receive signals from virtual cameras.
When I disable built-in camera and recommand, this is result:
[image: Result]

The obtained results show that when the built-in camera is disabled, the Android Subsystem cannot receive any signal from the Virtual Camera.
Has anyone been in a similar situation and is there a fix? I have tried many different ways, using different software but the results are still not satisfactory. I want the apps on ASW to use the virtual camera but they still only receive the inbuilt camera and not the virtual camera.
Looking forward to everyone's response.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'd encourage you to read [why we typically ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) and edit your post to include the relevant text.  Thanks!